# ¿Cómo pasar datos entre pantallas con PHP?

Tags: php, html, netbeans

Soy nuevo en esto de PHP, estoy intentando pasar variables de un formulario en el index a otra página local del mismo proyecto. No entiendo muy bien cómo se hace. He probado con el método post, pero la otra pagina no recibe nada. A continuación pondré la parte del código en el index donde yo estoy mandando los datos:

código html en index.php

```
<p>Nombre: <input type="text" id="id_name" name="nombre" size="40" placeholder="Tu nombre" required="true" minlength="4" maxlength="20"></p>
```

codigo php en index.php

```
<?php
        $nombre = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nombre");
        $edad = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "edad");
        $fnacim = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nacim");
        $sexo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "sexo");
        $lenguaje = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lenguaje");
        echo '<a href="paginados.php?nombre='.$nombre.' & edad='.$edad.' & nacim = '.$fnacim.' & sexo = '.$sexo.' & lenguaje = '.$lenguaje.'">Mi enlace</a>';      
?>
```

Y en index2 lo muestro (en este caso solo estoy mostrando una variable) de esta forma:

```
    <?php
        $nombre = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "nombre");
        $edad = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "edad");
        $fnacim = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "nacim");
        $sexo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "sexo");
        $lenguaje = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "lenguaje");
        echo '<p> Hola: ' .$nombre. '. Tienes '.$edad.' años. Naciste el ' .$fnacim. ', eres ' .$sexo. ' y tu lenguaje preferido es ' .$lenguaje.'</p>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varias cosas:
Estás declarando dos variables en cada línea (`$nombre` y `$action`, `$edad` y nuevamente `$action`, etc.), cuando no existe ninguna necesidad. Prescinde de `$action`.

Luego, estás utilizando mal `filter_input()` tanto en *index* como en *index2*:

En *index*, no tiene sentido mucho sentido la comprobación que haces en cada línea para decidir si le asignas el valor del `filter_input()` o si le asignas un string vacío porque, de no existir el valor en el filtro, éste devolverá `NULL` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php#refsect1-function.filter-input-returnvalues) y a efectos prácticos ya se imprimirá como un string vacío.

En *index2*, estás pasando mal el segundo parámetro de la función, que debe ser únicamente el nombre de la variable. Piénsalo: si en *index* pones correctamente `filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nombre")` y no escribes `filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST["nombre"])`, ¿qué sentido tiene poner `filter_input(INPUT_GET, $_GET["nombre"])` en lugar de `filter_input(INPUT_GET, "nombre")`?

Para finalizar, también está mal el enlace porque no estás separando las variables con un ampersand (`&`) y no has usado `echo` para que te lo imprima.

```
<?php

    // Obteniendo los valores del formulario, en caso de que estén vacíos devuelve NULL
    $nombre   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nombre");
    $edad     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "edad");
    $fnacim   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nacim");
    $sexo     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "sexo");
    $lenguaje = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lenguaje");

    // Echo para imprimir y ampersand entre variables: nombre=valor&edad=valor
    echo '<a href="index2.php?nombre=' . $nombre . '&edad=' . $edad . '">Mi enlace</a>';
      
?>

<?php

    echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, "nombre");

?>
```

Comment: Hola. Actualicé la pregunta por el código ya cambiado, pero me sigue sin mostrar nada. Gracias por la explicación.

Comment: No debes añadir espacios al ampersand que incluyes en tu dirección. Corrígelo e indica qué URL te sale en el navegador cuando haces clic en el enlace.

Comment: Vale, acabo de corregirlo. La url me sale tal que así: http://localhost/PhpProject1/index2.php?nombre=&edad=&nacim=&sexo=&lenguaje=

Comment: Fíjate que en la URL que pusiste todos los valores que pasas están vacíos, ninguno tiene un valor, así que es normal que index2 no muestre nada. Revisa el código HTML del formulario porque es lo más probable es que los campos de POST no estén llegando bien a index.